# Compiling a java program to a jar errors in eclipse

Tags: java, opengl, compiler-construction, jar, lwjgl

I have created a Java program. It it is a game made with LWJGL. I have decided to import some textures with the built in Texture class from LWJGL (LWJGL is Light Weight Java Graphics Library with opengl). In Eclipse I have put src/imagename.png. It works in Eclipse. I export it into a jar file and run it (After putting required libraries and natives) and it does not run and can't find the file. So, I tried removing that and putting imagename.png. That didn't work either. I tried putting /imagename.png and it still didn't work. What should I do?

```
try {
        player = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream(new File("src/player.png")));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
```

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You might want to show us the error message and the code that causes it. Also, you know that files don't exist inside of jar files, right? That only resources do.

Comment: How are you loading the images?

Comment: Do I have to use the getClass().getResourceAsStream("/classpath/to/my/file")

Comment: Yep, you're trying to get resources in jars as files. Answer: don't. Search this site for similar questions as it's been asked many times.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Class.getResourceAsStream() or ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream) are the proper ways to get files from the Classpath, which is what you should be trying to do if you want to load your files from inside of a jar.